# Yii2 using AppAseets right way?

Tags: yii2, assetbundle

I have added the assets file(css, js) in assets/AppAssets.php

example:

```
public $css = [       
       
        'css/style.css',
        'css/page-builder.css',
        'css/settings.css',
        'css/style-core.css',
        'css/style-custom.css',
    ];    
    public $js = [
       'js/jquery.min.js',
       'js/jquery-migrate.min.js',
       'js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js',
       'js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js',
       'js/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js',
       'js/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js',
       'js/revolution.extension.kenburn.min.js',
       'js/revolution.extension.navigation.min.js',
       'js/revolution.extension.parallax.min.js',
       'js/revolution.extension.actions.min.js',
       'js/revolution.extension.video.min.js',
       'js/script.js',
       'js/page-builder.js',
       'js/effect.min.js',
       'js/plugins.min.js',
    ];
    public $jsOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD];
    public $depends = [
      //  'yii\web\YiiAsset',   
    ];
```

I have layouts like main, home, articles, gallery etc.
In the main layout I am using:

```
use app\assets\AppAsset;
AppAsset::register($this);
```

Now for home layout only, I need js/revolution*, but not for other layouts like article,
whereas for gallery layout I need to include some js files like `mislider.js`, I also want to maintain the order.

I tried to create a separate asset bundle for example assets/Home.php, which will only have `revolution*.js` files, but couldn't find a way, how I can the maintain the loading order as shown above.

Comment: You can create diffrent diffrent Assets and use it in layout as per requirement

Comment: If you make your `Home` assets bundle dependent on `AppAsset` bundle the js from `AppAsset` will be loaded first.

Comment: @MichalHynčica - Can you add a example, how I can call AppAsset in Home assets?

Comment: You already have an example in your `AppAsset`. It's `$depends` property. Just put the `app\assets\AppAsset` class into `$depends` property of your `Home` bundle.